# What is the best way to install helm charts having vault secrets on local k8s cluster?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, hashicorp-vault, argocd, vault

I use helm charts for k8s deployment. And chart has secrets from Hashicorp's `Vault` and I use ArgoCD to automate deployments and `argocd-vault-plugin` take care injecting vault secrets from vault server before installing helm charts on GKE k8s cluster.

All good until now.

I would like to understand how this works for charts deployments (`helm install`) to local k8s cluster. What is the recommended way of charts (with vault secrets) installing on local k8s cluster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [install](https://argocd-vault-plugin.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation/#installing-locally) / use argocd-vault-plugin from CLI

ie.

```
# generate helm template, pipe to vault plugin to inject secrets, pipe to kubectl to apply
# ensure you are targeting the correct cluster
helm template my-app ./path -f env/values.yaml | argocd-vault-plugin generate - | kubectl apply -f -
```

Dependencies:
You will need to have access to vault locally, and set some environment vars. Source: https://argocd-vault-plugin.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/#environment-variables